# Display item created date on Infopath form

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, infopath

can anyone please tell me how to display item created date on infopath form.
I have retrieved created date from library and added to infopath form but it's showing the Library created date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just insert a control of the type `Calculated Value` in your form, click *`fx`* and then click `Insert Field or Group` and select the field `Created`. Click OK.

Right click on the field again, select `Calculated Value Properties` and at the bottom of the dialog there is a dropdown called `Format as`. Select `Date & Time` and then click the button to the right called `Format`. Here you can select the appropriate format on the date.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but still i'm getting library created date on infopath form